# Reset all form controls to valid/pristine but keep existing form values

Tags: angular

I'm using template driven forms in Angular 5. I have a `Field A` and a `Field B`. Depending how `Field A` is answered, it could make `Field B` invalid.

So I submit the form with a value in `Field A` that makes `Field B` invalid and I show a validation next to `Field B`. Now, I change the `Field A` value to make `Field B` valid. I then submit my form, but `Field B` still has `ng-invalid` on it because I didn't touch it...I only modified `Field A`.

Is there a way I can remove all validations (`ng-invalid`) from every control when I go to submit my form? Or what is a way I can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the change event of your **Field A** you can do this:

```
(change)="yourForm.controls.fieldB.updateValueAndValidity()"
```

*I have not tried it if it works, but you can try:*

```
(change)="fieldB.updateValueAndValidity()"
```